# Add data in MySQL using Android with php page

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I want to Send data on PHP page from Android App and PHP page store data in My SQL.
when i'm send data to PHP and store for database. android app successfully send request to php page and they store data in database. but Value that enter in Android app can not store in database.

PHP Code

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_mail = $_POST['email'];
$user_pass = $_POST['password'];
$user_ip = getRealIpAddr();

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, ip_add, created_at) VALUES ('$user_name', '$user_mail', '$user_pass', '$user_ip',Now())";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and Android XMl File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="38dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="94dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="160dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="60dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="217dp"
        android:onClick="onsignup"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code here

```
username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    }

    public void onsignup(View view){
        String user = username.getText().toString();
        String mail = email.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();
        String type = "signup";

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type,user,mail,pass);
    }
```

BackgroundWorker Class code here

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        String type = params[0];
        String signup_url = "http://192.168.0.104/android/signup.php";
        if (type.equals("signup")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String email = params[2];
                String password = params[3];

                URL url = new URL(signup_url);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));

                String result = "";
                String line = "";

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result+=line;

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Signup Status");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String user_name) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(user_name);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

It's all file of Coding i have also permission internet of manifest file
but i don't know problem exactly where is it.
Thank You for Helping

Comment: In your code where are you storing data ? There is no database nor sharedpreference.

Comment: if you see last code i'm send data to my php page link and then php code store in database

Comment: i see complete xml manifest (useless for this post) and incomplete php (probably most useful). Do you even know if the php gets called ?  debug, exception handling, some kind of logging, apache logs, php logs ????? anything ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg yes i have idea about logging but it's main issue in Android java class BackgroundWorker that not send data that put in XML file

Comment: ok ... stacktrace ? http status ? compile error ? debug log? logcat ? anything ???

Comment: Sorry It's all code Working Fine just url file name mistake from my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code is 100% working and save data to MySQL database just URL page Mistake accrued from my site

```
String signup_url = "http://192.168.0.104/android/signup.php";
```

Thats signu.php file name error that's why i faced this issue